# sql query: column by id multiple times

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, multiple-columns

SQL newb here. 
I am having troubles to create a select statement.

I have one table `REF` with an id and a value v;

```
+-----+----+
| REF |    |
+-----+----+
| ID  |  V |
| 1   | 10 |
| 2   | 20 |
| 3   | 30 |
| 4   | 40 |
| 5   | 50 |
| 6   | 60 |
| 7   | 70 |
+-----+----+
```

in a second table `IND` i have three columns with id-values;

```
+-----+-----+-----+
|IND  |     |     |
|-----|-----|-----|
| ID1 | ID2 | ID3 |
| 1   | 2   |     |
|     | 3   | 4   |
| 5   |     |     |
| 6   |     | 7   |
```

I want to receive the value of REF.v accordinlgly in each of the three columns (Table RES); the ids are distinct, there is no overlapping in between.

```
+-----+-----+-----+
| RES |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+
| ID1 | ID2 | ID3 |
| 10  | 20  |     |
|     | 30  | 40  |
| 50  |     |     |
| 60  |     | 70  |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). (**[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query your `IND` table, using three subqueries to retrieve the value linked to used id

Try this:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT V FROM REF WHERE REF.ID = IND.ID1) AS V_ID1,
    (SELECT V FROM REF WHERE REF.ID = IND.ID2) AS V_ID2,
    (SELECT V FROM REF WHERE REF.ID = IND.ID3) AS V_ID3
FROM IND
```

**UPDATE**

About two proposed solutions (`LEFT OUTER JOINs` Vs `SUBQUERIES`)

I've tried on Sql Fiddle under Postgres 9.6 engine.

Times are the same but execution plan about LEFT OUTER JOIN is more complex

You can see [**SqlFiddle SUBQUERIES**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/54099/2/0) and [**SqlFiddle LEFT OUTER JOINs**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/54099/1/0)

Comment: Isn't a subquery like that less efficient than a join?

Comment: left joins are expensives. Try it

Comment: @JoeTaras From the fiddles - _Left Outer Join_: Record Count: 4; Execution Time: **19ms** _Subqueries_:Record Count: 4; Execution Time: **35ms** - your query takes an extra 14ms, nearly double the time on this small dataset.

Comment: @Andrew I suppose this the net traffic. I've tested and the results are the same. Check the execution plan on Depesz

Comment: @JoeTaras No you're right the plan is more complex on the joins, but it is possible for a more complex plan to execute more efficiently if the steps are less expensive. Either way both our answers work.

Comment: Yes, either answers are OK

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ref1.V AS RefV1, ref2.V AS RefV2, ref3.V AS RefV3
FROM IND i 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ref ref1
ON ref1.ID = i.ID1
LEFT OUTER JOIN ref ref2
ON ref2.ID = i.ID2
LEFT OUTER JOIN ref ref3
ON ref3.ID = i.ID3
```

You connect the reference table three times, using a left outer join, which lets the reference table not match the IND table, resulting in nulls where you had missing IDs. Then you select the v value from each of these joined tables, being sure to alias it, so you can tell them apart.

Comment: Dear, I've updated my answer with test on Sqlfiddle for your query and mine.